# Ionic 2 how to check all checkboxes on button click and get checked checkboxes' value

Tags: angular, ionic2

I m fairly new in Angular 2 and hence Ionic 2, I have a little problem, can any body tell me how to check all checkboxes on button click?? and how to get value oc checked checkboxes on another button click.

Here is my how html looks like

```
<div class="card item-icon-right"  *ngFor="let item of items" >
    <ion-checkbox *ngIf="showCheckBoxes" [(ngModel)]="item.id" mode="ios"></ion-checkbox>
</div>
<button class="button button-calm">Check All</button>
<button class="button button-primary">Get selected Values</button>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can have two checkbox elements

1. For select All -to make all the elements based on one click(simply toggle)
2. Select particular

   ```
   <div class="card item-icon-right"  *ngFor="let item of items" >
        <ion-checkbox *ngIf="showCheckBoxes && selectedAll" [(ngModel)]="item.id" mode="ios" [checked]="selectedAll"></ion-checkbox>

        <ion-checkbox *ngIf="showCheckBoxes && !selectedAll" [(ngModel)]="item.id" mode="ios" ></ion-checkbox>
   </div>
   ```

   Check All
   Get selected Values

   ```
   checkAll(){
       this.selectedAll=true;
       console.log(this.items);
   }
   ```

When you are selecting all items then you are using the entire array as such.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why there are two <ion-checkbox> component inside loop??

Comment: first two lines in the answer explains that.

Comment: Yes i got it thanks, and how to get the array of item ids of selected checkbox?