# select all checkboxes in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have to select all checkboxes if user select 'All Neighbourhoods' checkbox in angular.  I tried with below code. But not working. How to fix this in angular 2?

**explore-list.Component.html**

```
    <div class="checkbox_cont">
        <div class="checkbox ">
            <!--<input id="modal_checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="categories" unchecked="">-->
            <input type="checkbox" name="allneighbourhoods"  [value]="allneighbourhoods" (change)="neighbourhoodname [$event.target.getAttribute('value')]=$event.target.checked" id="allneighbourhoods" ng-click="toggleSelect($event)" />
            <label for="allneighbourhoods">All Neighbourhoods</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal_line"></div>                                                  
    <div class="checkbox " *ngFor="let neighbourhood of neighbourhoods;let i=index;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="neighbourhoodname[{{i}}]"  [value]="neighbourhood" (change)="neighbourhoodname [$event.target.getAttribute('value')]=$event.target.checked" id="{{neighbourhood}}"  [checked]='true' />
        <label for="{{neighbourhood}}">{{neighbourhood}}</label>
    </div>
```

**explore-list.Component.ts**

```
    export class ExploreListComponent implements OnInit {  
        neighbourhoodname={};

        toggleSelect = function(event){       
            this.forEach(this.checkboxes, function(item){
                console.log(item);
                item.selected = event.target.checked;
            });
        }
    }
```

**neighbourhoods json**

[image]

Comment: Seems like duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059701/select-all-checkboxes-with-angular-js

Comment: @Learner, Im trying in angular 2.

Comment: you can refere to this [**solution**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132485/ionic-2-how-to-check-all-checkboxes-on-button-click-and-get-checked-checkboxes/43132696#43132696)

Comment: @Aravind, Not working.

Comment: is it fixed or you need some more help?

Comment: @Aravind Yes. It is fixed.  Sravan answer is working fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add `ngModel` to the check boxes,

**`[(ngModel)]="neighbourhood.selected"`**

```
<form #f="ngForm" novalidate>
   <div class="checkbox_cont">
       <div class="checkbox ">
           <input type="checkbox" id="allneighbourhoods" name="allneighbourhoods"  value="allneighbourhoods" (click)="toggleSelect($event)" />
           <label for="allneighbourhoods">All Neighbourhoods</label>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal_line"></div> 
     <div class="checkbox " *ngFor="let neighbourhood of neighbourhoods;let i=index;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="neighbourhoodname[{{i}}]"  [checked]="neighbourhood.selected" value="neighbourhood.selected" id="{{neighbourhood.name}}" (change)="neighbourhood.selected = !(neighbourhood.selected)"/>
      <label for="{{neighbourhood.name}}">{{neighbourhood.name}}</label>
   </div>
   <input type="button" (click)="ApplyFilters(f.valid)"  class="btn btn-primary filters_btn" value="Apply Filters">
</form>
```

Now, your function will be same,

```
export class ExploreListComponent implements OnInit {  

 neighbourhoods = [{"name":"Taito"},{"name":"Shinjuku"},{"name":"Shibuya"}];

 toggleSelect = function(event){  

        this.allneighbourhoods = event.target.checked;
        this.neighbourhoods.forEach(function(item){
         console.log(item);
         item.selected = event.target.checked;
      });

  }       

  ApplyFilters(isValid: boolean) {      
    var datas  = this.neighbourhoods.filter(function (data) { return data.selected == true });
  console.log(datas);
    if (!isValid) return;         

 }
}
```

I have added a **`selected property`**, so that the `selected value` of `main checkbox` will be the `model value` of all checkboxes.

[Here is a Working **DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/7ntN6LgsMF5JSbI2BXsP?p=preview)

Comment: I getting this error. class ExploreListComponent - inline template:100:15 caused by: this.forEach is not a function

Comment: the checkboxes neighbourhoods are dynamic.

Comment: Still im getting error. class ExploreListComponent - inline template:100:15 caused by: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: <div class="checkbox " *ngFor="let neighbourhood of `neighbourhoods`;let i=index;">. in this script `neighbourhoods` are dynamic.

Comment: you donot have `neighbourhoods` on your component?, check the DEMO I added, you will get an Idea

Comment: Im getting this error class ExploreListComponent - inline template:99:15 caused by: Cannot create property 'selected' on string 'West'

Comment: `item` varirable return  `West`,  `Central`, `North`, `East`  in console.

Comment: I cannot get all the values in `neighbourhoodname` on submit button click.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139742/discussion-between-sravan-and-vel).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044422/listview-to-details-view-without-calling-api-again